# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/runners/PipelineRunner after migrating to dataflow 2.x

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Getting runtime error:

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/runners/PipelineRunner"
```

even though I have below in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
        <version>[2.1.0, 2.99)</version>
    </dependency>
```

All compile time errors have been resolved after moving to 2.X, started getting runtime error.

mvn compile on this project also reports success. Just when I attempt to run the  pipeline from eclipse get this error.

Comment: Can you post more complete pom.xml? Are you building a fat-jar to run? Mostly likely cause is that beam jars are not included in your jar or classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added below to my `pom.xml` and deleted any all run profiles in `pom.xml` and error was resolved.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
      <version>[2.1.0, 2.99)</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The solution above worked for me as well. I had to make sure to delete the run profile (enclosed in <profiles> </profiles>) in the project's POM file, then Eclipse was able to run without throwing the runtime error in PUG's question above.